# Rows with a timestamp value yesterday in DB2

Tags: sql, casting, db2, query-optimization, sql-timestamp

How do I select rows with a timestamp value at any time yesterday? The DBMS is DB2.

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
 WHERE CAST (my_timestamp_col AS DATE) = CURRENT DATE - 1 DAY
```

This is what I currently have but is casting timestamps as date inefficient? Can it make use of indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would instead recommend:

```
where my_timestamp_col >= current date - 1 day and
      my_timestamp_col < current date
```

Comment: should point out that yes, casting from timestamp to date is inefficient.  Generally speaking, using a function on a table column results in a full table scan.  Unless you've built an index that includes that function.  (wihich may not be available on all platforms & versions of Db2)